# Nameerror when calling a user-defined function in another user-defined function

Tags: python

I need to write a program that opens and reads a file and contains separate user-defined functions for counting the number of lines and words in the file e.g. linecount(), wordcount()etc. I drafted the below code, but I keep getting a name error that says "global name 'f' is not defined". f is a file handle that should be returned by the openfile() function. Any advise?

```
#open and read file
def openfile():
    import string
    name = raw_input ("enter file name: ")
    f = open (name)

# Calculates the number of paragraphs within the file 
def linecount():
    openfile()
    lines = 0
    for line in f:
        lines = lines + 1
    return lines

#call function that counts lines
linecount()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `f` is local variable in openfile

```
def openfile():
    import string
    name = raw_input ("enter file name: ")
    return open (name)

# Calculates the number of paragraphs within the file 
def linecount():
    f = openfile()
    lines = 0
    for line in f:
        lines = lines + 1
    return lines
```

or even shorter

```
def file_line_count():
    file_name = raw_input("enter file name: ")
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        return sum(1 for line in f)
```

Comment: @ kAlmAcetA: Many thanks for your response and solution. Does the trick!